# Yocto Clang++: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.34' not found

Tags: yocto, glibc, amd-rocm

I'm building a custom Yocto image that has added HIPIFY as a package to be build on target. It has a dependency on LLVM+Clang that is leading to the following error after I add clang from the meta-clang layer to it's DEPENDS:

```
/home/zmolokwu/Ryzen_Workspace/zube_devel/poky/build/tmp/work/innoflight_cfc510_live_usb-innoflight-linux/hipify/1.0+git999-r0/recipe-sysroot/usr/bin/clang++: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.34' not found (required by /home/zmolokwu/Ryzen_Workspace/zube_devel/poky/build/tmp/work/innoflight_cfc510_live_usb-innoflight-linux/hipify/1.0+git999-r0/recipe-sysroot/usr/bin/clang++)
| /home/zmolokwu/Ryzen_Workspace/zube_devel/poky/build/tmp/work/innoflight_cfc510_live_usb-innoflight-linux/hipify/1.0+git999-r0/recipe-sysroot/usr/bin/clang++: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.32' not found (required by /home/zmolokwu/Ryzen_Workspace/zube_devel/poky/build/tmp/work/innoflight_cfc510_live_usb-innoflight-linux/hipify/1.0+git999-r0/recipe-sysroot/usr/bin/clang++)
| /home/zmolokwu/Ryzen_Workspace/zube_devel/poky/build/tmp/work/innoflight_cfc510_live_usb-innoflight-linux/hipify/1.0+git999-r0/recipe-sysroot/usr/bin/clang++: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.29' not found (required by /home/zmolokwu/Ryzen_Workspace/zube_devel/poky/build/tmp/work/innoflight_cfc510_live_usb-innoflight-linux/hipify/1.0+git999-r0/recipe-sysroot/usr/bin/../lib64/libclang-cpp.so.14)     
| /home/zmolokwu/Ryzen_Workspace/zube_devel/poky/build/tmp/work/innoflight_cfc510_live_usb-innoflight-linux/hipify/1.0+git999-r0/recipe-sysroot/usr/bin/clang++: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.34' not found (required by /home/zmolokwu/Ryzen_Workspace/zube_devel/poky/build/tmp/work/innoflight_cfc510_live_usb-innoflight-linux/hipify/1.0+git999-r0/recipe-sysroot/usr/bin/../lib64/libclang-cpp.so.14)     
| /home/zmolokwu/Ryzen_Workspace/zube_devel/poky/build/tmp/work/innoflight_cfc510_live_usb-innoflight-linux/hipify/1.0+git999-r0/recipe-sysroot/usr/bin/clang++: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.32' not found (required by /home/zmolokwu/Ryzen_Workspace/zube_devel/poky/build/tmp/work/innoflight_cfc510_live_usb-innoflight-linux/hipify/1.0+git999-r0/recipe-sysroot/usr/bin/../lib64/libclang-cpp.so.14)     
| /home/zmolokwu/Ryzen_Workspace/zube_devel/poky/build/tmp/work/innoflight_cfc510_live_usb-innoflight-linux/hipify/1.0+git999-r0/recipe-sysroot/usr/bin/clang++: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.29' not found (required by /home/zmolokwu/Ryzen_Workspace/zube_devel/poky/build/tmp/work/innoflight_cfc510_live_usb-innoflight-linux/hipify/1.0+git999-r0/recipe-sysroot/usr/bin/../lib64/libLLVM-14.so)
| /home/zmolokwu/Ryzen_Workspace/zube_devel/poky/build/tmp/work/innoflight_cfc510_live_usb-innoflight-linux/hipify/1.0+git999-r0/recipe-sysroot/usr/bin/clang++: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.34' not found (required by /home/zmolokwu/Ryzen_Workspace/zube_devel/poky/build/tmp/work/innoflight_cfc510_live_usb-innoflight-linux/hipify/1.0+git999-r0/recipe-sysroot/usr/bin/../lib64/libLLVM-14.so)
| /home/zmolokwu/Ryzen_Workspace/zube_devel/poky/build/tmp/work/innoflight_cfc510_live_usb-innoflight-linux/hipify/1.0+git999-r0/recipe-sysroot/usr/bin/clang++: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.32' not found (required by /home/zmolokwu/Ryzen_Workspace/zube_devel/poky/build/tmp/work/innoflight_cfc510_live_usb-innoflight-linux/hipify/1.0+git999-r0/recipe-sysroot/usr/bin/../lib64/libLLVM-14.so)
| /home/zmolokwu/Ryzen_Workspace/zube_devel/poky/build/tmp/work/innoflight_cfc510_live_usb-innoflight-linux/hipify/1.0+git999-r0/recipe-sysroot/usr/bin/clang++: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.33' not found (required by /home/zmolokwu/Ryzen_Workspace/zube_devel/poky/build/tmp/work/innoflight_cfc510_live_usb-innoflight-linux/hipify/1.0+git999-r0/recipe-sysroot/usr/bin/../lib64/libLLVM-14.so)
| /home/zmolokwu/Ryzen_Workspace/zube_devel/poky/build/tmp/work/innoflight_cfc510_live_usb-innoflight-linux/hipify/1.0+git999-r0/recipe-sysroot/usr/bin/clang++: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.33' not found (required by /home/zmolokwu/Ryzen_Workspace/zube_devel/poky/build/tmp/work/innoflight_cfc510_live_usb-innoflight-linux/hipify/1.0+git999-r0/recipe-sysroot/usr/bin/../lib64/libstdc++.so.6)
| /home/zmolokwu/Ryzen_Workspace/zube_devel/poky/build/tmp/work/innoflight_cfc510_live_usb-innoflight-linux/hipify/1.0+git999-r0/recipe-sysroot/usr/bin/clang++: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.32' not found (required by /home/zmolokwu/Ryzen_Workspace/zube_devel/poky/build/tmp/work/innoflight_cfc510_live_usb-innoflight-linux/hipify/1.0+git999-r0/recipe-sysroot/usr/bin/../lib64/libstdc++.so.6)
| /home/zmolokwu/Ryzen_Workspace/zube_devel/poky/build/tmp/work/innoflight_cfc510_live_usb-innoflight-linux/hipify/1.0+git999-r0/recipe-sysroot/usr/bin/clang++: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.34' not found (required by /home/zmolokwu/Ryzen_Workspace/zube_devel/poky/build/tmp/work/innoflight_cfc510_live_usb-innoflight-linux/hipify/1.0+git999-r0/recipe-sysroot/usr/bin/../lib64/libstdc++.so.6)
| /home/zmolokwu/Ryzen_Workspace/zube_devel/poky/build/tmp/work/innoflight_cfc510_live_usb-innoflight-linux/hipify/1.0+git999-r0/recipe-sysroot/usr/bin/clang++: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.33' not found (required by /home/zmolokwu/Ryzen_Workspace/zube_devel/poky/build/tmp/work/innoflight_cfc510_live_usb-innoflight-linux/hipify/1.0+git999-r0/recipe-sysroot/usr/bin/../lib64/../lib64/libedit.so.0)  
| /home/zmolokwu/Ryzen_Workspace/zube_devel/poky/build/tmp/work/innoflight_cfc510_live_usb-innoflight-linux/hipify/1.0+git999-r0/recipe-sysroot/usr/bin/clang++: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.28' not found (required by /home/zmolokwu/Ryzen_Workspace/zube_devel/poky/build/tmp/work/innoflight_cfc510_live_usb-innoflight-linux/hipify/1.0+git999-r0/recipe-sysroot/usr/bin/../lib64/../lib64/libxml2.so.2)  
| /home/zmolokwu/Ryzen_Workspace/zube_devel/poky/build/tmp/work/innoflight_cfc510_live_usb-innoflight-linux/hipify/1.0+git999-r0/recipe-sysroot/usr/bin/clang++: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.33' not found (required by /home/zmolokwu/Ryzen_Workspace/zube_devel/poky/build/tmp/work/innoflight_cfc510_live_usb-innoflight-linux/hipify/1.0+git999-r0/recipe-sysroot/usr/bin/../lib64/../lib64/libxml2.so.2)  
| /home/zmolokwu/Ryzen_Workspace/zube_devel/poky/build/tmp/work/innoflight_cfc510_live_usb-innoflight-linux/hipify/1.0+git999-r0/recipe-sysroot/usr/bin/clang++: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.34' not found (required by /home/zmolokwu/Ryzen_Workspace/zube_devel/poky/build/tmp/work/innoflight_cfc510_live_usb-innoflight-linux/hipify/1.0+git999-r0/recipe-sysroot/usr/bin/../lib64/../lib64/libxml2.so.2)  
| /home/zmolokwu/Ryzen_Workspace/zube_devel/poky/build/tmp/work/innoflight_cfc510_live_usb-innoflight-linux/hipify/1.0+git999-r0/recipe-sysroot/usr/bin/clang++: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.29' not found (required by /home/zmolokwu/Ryzen_Workspace/zube_devel/poky/build/tmp/work/innoflight_cfc510_live_usb-innoflight-linux/hipify/1.0+git999-r0/recipe-sysroot/usr/bin/../lib64/../lib64/libxml2.so.2)
```

This is on an Ubuntu 18.04 LTS Machine.

I've checked my current ldd version:

```
ldd (Ubuntu GLIBC 2.27-3ubuntu1.6) 2.27
Copyright (C) 2018 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
Written by Roland McGrath and Ulrich Drepper.
```

And I see that my build machine's GLIBC is 2.27. Is there a way of altering the recipe or cmake build in order to make use of GLIBC libraries from Yocto rather than my local machine? Or is the only option to upgrade and build this image on the appropriate Ubuntu version?